# not appearing properly in "Name" at SQlite Example

Tags: sqlite

```
SELECT "Title", "Name" FROM "albums"
LEFT JOIN "artists" ON "artists. ArtistId" = "albums. ArtistId"
```

I want to use the left join statement to expose only the title and name attributes of the albums table and artists table. If you look at the http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/ site that I refer to, I think I applied it properly, but the values ​​of name are not appearing properly. What am I doing wrong?

- There are 'albums' table and 'artists' table in DB, 'AlbumId', 'Title', and 'ArtistId' items in 'albums' table and 'ArtistId' and 'Name' items in 'artists' table.

For reference, DB is sample DB downloaded from http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLtZg.png)

Comment: Always best to explain "not appearing properly" when asking a question

Comment: I assume you mean https://www.sqltutorial.net?  I can't see any obvious sample DB download link.  Could you provide one please?  I had to make some assumptions in my answer as I can't see the database. - or just provide more information about the database structure.

Comment: @GPW sry :( it was http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/                                                                            
There are 'albums' table and 'artists' table in DB, 'AlbumId', 'Title', and 'ArtistId' items in 'albums' table and 'ArtistId' and 'Name' items in 'artists' table.

Comment: @dbmitch thank you :) I edit it

Answer (score 0):

Since OP clarified which site he was getting the DB from, edited now..)
try something like (untested, but I think should work assuming the tables BOTH have a TITLE and a NAME - if not, change accordingly)

```
select alb.Title as AlbumTitle, 
art.Name as ArtistName
from albums alb
left join artists art on (art.artistid=alb.artistid)
```

This should work.  If it doesn't then you may have an album with an artist that doesn't exist.  As someone else said, you don't need to quote all the fields and table names, and using aliases for the tables rather than full table names is a bit cleaner (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

You can quote table/column names, but that is not necessary if they are no SQL keywords.

Anyway, `artists.ArtistId` contains *two* names, which must be quoted separately:

```
... ON "artists"."ArtistId" = "albums"."ArtistId"
```